# Airflow: configure datetime variables via the web app

Tags: airflow

### Question

- Is it possible to configure a datetime typed variable via the web app?
  For example, If I want to change the value of the **start_date** variable.
- I know how to configure string or numerical values through the web app. But just wondering whether I can do the same for datetime variables? I have had a look [here](https://airflow.apache.org/macros.html) at using macros. But didn't have any success. I have also tried adding raw string values, but that didn't work either
- I am aware that I can define **start_date** as a string in my DAG file and then convert it to a datetime object within the file. That isn't what I'm asking
- Please note that this question is specifically about setting the value of a datetime variable from the web app. I would also be interested in setting it from the cli. Anything that does not require a code change. Thanks

Comment: what is `web app`? Do you want to change `start_date` of some `Dag` using airflow `UI`(`airflow web-server`)?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar yes, exactly that